# Index Match from closed workbook with variable file path

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following which works as it references the open TypeList workbook and matches on two criteria to return appropriate value.

```
With Sheets(wsname)
        .Range("N2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX([TypeList]List!$B$2:$D$1000,MATCH(1,([TypeList]List!$B$2:$B$1000=K2)*([TypeList]List!$A$2:$A$1000=""CVA""),0),3)"
        .Range("N2:N" & lRow).FillDown
End With
```

What I'm trying is to avoid opening the TypeList workbook and instead reference the range inside the closed workbook.  I've assigned the file path and ranges

```
sPath = Application.UserLibraryPath
sPath2 = Application.UserLibraryPath
sPath3 = Application.UserLibraryPath
sPath = sPath & "[TypeList]List'!$B$2:$D$1000"
sPath2 = sPath2 & "[TypeList]List'!$A$2:$A$1000"
sPath3 = sPath3 & "[TypeList]List'!$B$2:$B$1000"
```

so I thought this would work

```
.Range("N2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(sPath,MATCH(1,(sPath3=K2)*(sPath2=""CVA""),0),3)"
```

which only returns #NAME so I assume it's not seeing the closed workbook but I'm sure what direction to go.

Comment: Try this `.Range("N2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & sPath & ",MATCH(1,(" & sPath3 & "=K2)*(" & sPath2 & "=""CVA""),0),3)"`.  You need to remove the variables from the quotes.

Comment: that looked promising but 'unable to set the formularray property of the range class' err.

Comment: try this as a regular formula not an array: `.Range("N2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & sPath & ",MATCH(1,INDEX(" & sPath3 & "=K2)*(" & sPath2 & "=""CVA""),),0),3)"`

Comment: That didn't work either.  Appreciate your input.

Comment: I think I see the problem potentially.  The formula ends up being 305 chars long.  Perhaps breaking it up will help.

Comment: I had a typo, did you try `.Range("N2").Formula = "=INDEX(" & sPath & ",MATCH(1,INDEX(" & sPath3 & "=K2)*(" & sPath2 & "=""CVA""),),0),3)"`?

Comment: I did, i knew what you were going for

Comment: You are missing a `'` in the beginning of the string.  Change this `sPath = sPath & "[TypeList]List'!$B$2:$D$1000"` to this `sPath = "'" & sPath & "[TypeList]List'!$B$2:$D$1000"`

Comment: Okay, that last suggestion and just using as a Formula get's it working, not getting my desired result `#N/A` but at least the Formula gets entered.

Comment: So your formula in the cell is correct but returns "N/A"?  That usually means that the criteria was not found.  It has to find the value in Column K **and** "CVA" in their respective columns.

Comment: That is correct and it should find a match.  Confirmed by looking at the workbook and by using the orig formula.  Thanks for assistance.  2 free internet beers for you.